# Creating a true master detail view using Search web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, filter

The requirements are: Search Result web part 1 shows all master elements ( e.g buildings ) , once a building is selected then Search Result web part 2 should show all equipment in that building.

I plan on using two Search result web part and two Search boxes related to those results web parts.
An alternative could perhaps be the tweak the control and item display of a single results web part or use the hover panel to show the equipment.

Any ideas on the best way to proceed? Thanks

Comment: Is the search web part a requirement? If the buildings all in one list and the equipment are in a second list, then you can use connected list web parts. You tagged with question with [tag:sharepoint-online]... does your solution need to work with the "modern UI"?

Comment: The search is a requirement as the buildings are based on a number of slightly different Content types on serveral site collections.  Classic UI is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can satisfy this requirement using string query passing in the content search. For this purpose you create a customized url for all Items in master search page that refrence a detailed page as below:

```
http:....../DetailPage.aspx?buildings=[Complete in display template using the correct value]
```

then you crate a dynamic page 'Detail Pag' with a content search webpart which fetch data from Url Query string (It is handy in content search by Query Builder) like this:

```
BuildingManagedProperty:{url.buildingparameter}
```

The above syntax may not exact but you can easily build it in Content Search web part. By this method when you press the Item in master search page you redirect to dynamic detail page. If you need I can help you remotely just make me informed!